# Action Bar with custom font and back arrow

Tags: android, fonts, android-actionbar, back

I'm trying to customize the font in one activity action bar. I managed to do it by using this code during activity's onCreate:

```
if(getSupportActionBar()!=null){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.secondary_toolbar);
        TextView actionBarTitle = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        actionBarTitle.setText(R.string.new_payment_method);
    }
```

The problem is that if I change the toolbar to a custom layout, the code lines which enables the arrow to let the activity to navigate to the previous activity doesn't work anymore. I'm stuck finding a way to modify the font in the action bar and showing the back arrow which allows me to navigate back, at the same time.

Comment: Try yourCustomToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener. then inside onclick use onBackPressed(); or any thing else you want

Comment: In that case, I must implement extra listener, I was trying to use the back button on the action bar, that android has already. For using the back key I don't need to implement nothing at all, the default behaviour is to navigate back. I just want to change the fontFamily